While performing JOIN function which clause to use for higher efficiency ON clause or Using clause?
Is the speed of execution is affected by use of multiple clauses.
While practicing on leetCode sometimes some answers are faster with USING clause while some are faster with ON clause.
Is the situation any different with different types of joins.

USING usually appears in a natural join.  Regardless, your question is too broad without specifying a) an actual SQL database, and b) a query.
